# How to use R to extract the file name in the absolute path

Tags: r, stringr

```
x <- 'D:/r4ds/map.json/baishan.json'
```

I just wanna get "baishan".How can I realize it?

Answer (score 2):

You use `basename` + `file_path_sans_ext` from `tools`.

```
x <- 'D:/r4ds/map.json/baishan.json'
tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(x))
#[1] "baishan"
```

---

Using pure regex :

```
sub('.*/(.*)\\..*', '\\1', x)
```

This extracts everything after last `"/"` till the following dot (`"."`).

Comment: `sub("(.*?)\\.[^\\.]+$", "\\1", basename(x), perl = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
sub('.*/([^/.]+).*', "\\1", x)
#[1] "baishan
```